# Genymotion how to hide back/home/menu button that shown after ALT button pressed

Tags: keyboard, genymotion

This button shown up after pressing ALT button, that automatically show virtual keyboard (but all I want to do is ALT+TAB). How to make them disappear?

Or how to disable calling virtual keyboard when pressing ALT?

[image: these buttons]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you can find it on android setting

`keyboard & input > Virtual keyboard > Android keyboard setting Advanced > Emoji for physical keyboard`

disable it!

Comment: can not find this setting in android 9

Comment: Can also be Languages & input (august 2021)

Answer (score 1):

Settings for Android 9:
`settings > system > languages & input > virtual keyboard > Android keyboard settings (AOSP)  > Advanced > Emoji for physical keyboard (Disable it)`